# PDFBox - How to click a link in a PDF file to move to another page and underline specific text inside it?

Tags: javascript, pdf, hyperlink, pdfbox

In Adobe Acrobat i can define a link in the PDF file and set a JavaScript action when it's being clicked to go to another page and underline a specific word in that page, as it appears in this image:

[image]

I would like to do the same thing using Java's PDFBox library. I have succeeded in defining a link, but how to set the JavaScript code for that link to move to another page and underline a specific word in that page?

Here is my current code:

```
PDAnnotationLink myLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
/*
 * Some code here to define the link, then i should define the link action.
 */
PDActionJavaScript javascriptAction = new PDActionJavaScript( "app.alert(     \"I should now go to page 10 and undeline a word out there.\" );" );
myLink.setAction( javascriptAction );
annotations.add( myLink );
```

Comment: The annotation link should also have a rectangle. See the AddAnnotations.java example in the source code download. Assuming you did do that, what happens when you click on the link - does it show the alert or not?

Comment: Yes, it shows the alert, but how to set the link to do the other actions that Adobe Acrobat does; move to another page and highlight a word inside that page?

Comment: OK, so JS works. Now if you use that command "this.addAnnot()" - does anything happen? Can you share a simple PDF file with Adobe and share it here? I wonder if there's a sort of PDF library in the PDF and I'd like to have a look at it with PDFDebugger to see where it is.

Comment: I meant to write " I wonder if there's a sort of Javascript library in the PDF"

Comment: No, there isn't. I create the PDF file using Adobe Acrobat only. Would you like to see this sample PDF that i've created using Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: Here is a PDF sample: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zxzna9x88zcjwec/PDF%20with%20a%20link%20to%20go%20to%20another%20page%20%2B%20underline%20a%20word%20in%20that%20page.pdf?dl=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action is a GoTo action, and it has the page 2 object as destination. And it has a "Next" entry, and THAT one has the Javascript action.

This code replicates what Adobe has been doing:

```
List<PDAnnotation> annotations = pdfDocument.getPage(0).getAnnotations();
PDAnnotationLink myLink = new PDAnnotationLink();
myLink.setRectangle(new PDRectangle(122.618f, 706.037f, 287.127f-122.618f, 718.255f-706.037f));
myLink.setColor(new PDColor(new float[]{1, 1 / 3f, 0}, PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE));
PDBorderStyleDictionary bs = new PDBorderStyleDictionary();
bs.setWidth(3);
bs.setStyle(PDBorderStyleDictionary.STYLE_UNDERLINE);            
myLink.setBorderStyle(bs);

PDPageFitRectangleDestination dest = new PDPageFitRectangleDestination();
dest.setLeft(48);
dest.setBottom(401);
dest.setRight(589);
dest.setTop(744);
dest.setPage(pdfDocument.getPage(1));
PDActionGoTo gotoAction = new PDActionGoTo();
gotoAction.setDestination(dest);
List<PDAction> actionList = new ArrayList<>();
String js = "var annot = this.addAnnot({\n"
        + "page: 1,\n"
        + "type: \"Underline\",\n"
        + "quads: this.getPageNthWordQuads(1, 4),\n"
        + "author: \"Brad Colin\",\n"
        + "contents: \"Fifth word on page 2\"\n"
        + "});";
PDActionJavaScript jsAction = new PDActionJavaScript(js);
actionList.add(jsAction);
gotoAction.setNext(actionList);
myLink.setAction(gotoAction);

annotations.add(myLink);

pdfDocument.save("1-new.pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks Tilman! ... Are you sure it works? ... I have tested it but nothing happens in the PDF file! .. Here is the complete code that i've tried: https://pastebin.com/VkgtM6Wd

Comment: How about saving the modified document?

Comment: I forgot that, sorry! .. I've saved it now, but still no change! .. Here's the output PDF: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oo1rioveocf8cj5/1.pdf?dl=1

Comment: Ok, I see the problem... my code used the existing annotation from your file. That one had a rectangle (not to be confused with the destination rectangle). The result file doesn't have the annotation rectangle. (See my very first comment from Jan 28)

Comment: Did you understand my last comment, or do you want me to add code that creates the rectangle to the answer?

Comment: I hope you could modify my code sample pastebin.com/VkgtM6Wd to create this rectangle annotation so i could understand this.

Comment: I have updated my answer instead. You may have to click on the yellow bar in Adobe Reader for it to work, depending on your security settings.

Comment: Perfect Tilman. Just a small question; can i highlight the word in the second page instead of underlining it in the JavaScript code?

Comment: Oh, i can use type: \"Highlight\" + instead of type: \"Underline\". All is okay now :)